# Unlock Phone without the Screen (neither seeing anything nor touch is possible) or USB-Debugging

Tags: data-recovery, sim-unlocking, broken-screen

I have a problem with my mothers **Samsung Galaxy S3**. The Screen is completly dark and it seems like the phone doesn't react to touches.
There are pictures and contacts at the internal storage, wich are needed.

The Phone isn't rooted, the USB-Debugging is disabled, adb doesn't recognize the device and now i don't know what to do. I can't use a remote device like a mouse to unlock it, since i can't see where the mouse is.

I'm an IT student so feel free to use technical terms :)

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! While waiting for answers, have a look at our [broken-screen tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info) – you might find your issue covered there already ;)